# jQuery Find class when class attributes contain multiple class names (class="classA classB classC")

Tags: jquery, class, find

I have a div structure like this [simple menu]:

```
<div class="float menuA">
    <div class="float selected"></div>
    <div class="float default"></div>
    <div class="float default"></div>
    <div class="float default"></div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

When I click on any div with a classname of "default" I would like to:

1. Use `.removeClass().addClass()` to swap the class called "selected" to "default"
2. Update the recently clicked div (with class=="default") to class=="selected"

This approach works fine when the class tags contain exactly ONE classname (for example: class="default" and class="selected") but when there is a space seperated list of classnames within a single class tag, things dont go so smoothly.

Question:
How do I find the element with class=="selected" when there are multiple classnames within a single tag?

Any help appreciated guys....

Comment: What do you need the default class for. If it is default why would you need a class?

Comment: So why do you need a default class?

Comment: If you need it for styling, I would apply the style to `menuA` rather than the children divs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make a navigation menu. The easiest way to do this is:

```
$(function() {
    $('div.menuA div.float').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('default');
        $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

This doesn't directly answer your question though. In order to 'find' an element that's a child of another element, use the `find()` method:

```
// finds all divs with class 'selected' in the div.menuA div
$('div.menuA').find('.selected');
```

And if you want to skip the extra `find()` call, you can just concatenate the dots together:

```
// selects divs with the classes 'selected' and 'default'
$('div.menuA div.selected.default');
```

Comment: Yeah thats perfect! siblings are children of the menuA ;)

Comment: You should follow your own advice since your code will make the `<div class="clear">` a selectable div. Also, your code does not work since `$(this).siblings('selected')` is incorrect - it should be `$(this).siblings('.selected')`.

Comment: @methodin Edited my answer to fix the mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.default').click(function(){
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected').addClass('default');
    $(this).removeClass('default').addClass('.selected');
});
```

Comment: As a general rule, try to write selectors that are as specific as possible. Not only does this prevent against unexpected behavior when you have multiple items with the same class name, but it also prevents against unnecessary DOM searching.

Comment: In this answer, he uses `$('.default')`. This searches the entire DOM for anything with the class `default` and attaches the click handler. Imagine if you had something else with the class `.default` though, like maybe a `<p>` tag. Now, whenever you click on the `<p>` tag, it will get the `selected` class added to it. Not expected behavior. Likewise, the same issue occurs with the `$('.selected')`. If you have three navigation menus, clicking on one of the menus will unselect everything from all THREE. Once again, unexpected behavior.

Comment: If you want the behavior to **only** apply to your menu, you should be selecting only the menu in your jQuery calls. Likewise, if you only want something to act on the siblings of that menu, you should use the appropriate selectors. This example seems trivial, but when you start designing Rich Internet Applications (RIA), it becomes crucial that your jQuery selectors aren't accidentally selecting other elements in the page.

Comment: As for the unnecessary DOM searching, look at the `$('.selected')` call. You're searching the entire DOM **again** for anything with the `selected` class. Since you're already 'in' the right div, it would be much faster to just start from there and get its siblings (this means avoiding doing things like `$('div.menuA .selected')`, since that will search the entire DOM again. Once again, this example is trivial, but if your DOM structure is big or the user's computer is slow, it becomes an important optimization.